# Can I get Frozen Synapse on my non-Steam computer without having to buy it again?

Tags: steam, frozen-synapse

I recently received a [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/) gift activation for *[Frozen Synapse](http://www.frozensynapse.com/)*.  It downloaded without any issues, and I registered my account to be able to play the game online.

However, I have another computer, that doesn't have Steam on it, and I **don't intend to install Steam on it**, at least not in the foreseeable future.  I'd really like to get *Frozen Synapse* on this machine though, but it seems to me that the only way to download the game again without Steam is to purchase it from the game's website, which is unideal.

Is there any way that I can get a version of the game that can be activated with my *Frozen Synapse* account or something?

Comment: Why don't you want to install steam on that other computer?

Comment: You can install steam on a PC and leave it in offline mode if you're worried about bandwidth/security/ect issues. But otherwise the answer is no, you'll have to use steam to download and activate the game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  After playing the Steam-installed version of Frozen Synapse (so that you have a registered account and email address), you can go to Mode7's website and [use the form there](http://www.mode7games.com/support/getURL.php) to request a link to download and install a copy of Frozen Synapse independently of Steam.

Note also that the Steam-installed copy can be run without going through Steam.  Just browse into the install directory and run the exe directly.  (Don't use the desktop icon created by Steam, as that runs it via a steam:// URL instead of starting the exe directly.)

I have personally used both of these methods, having initially installed FS on my dual-boot laptop via Steam, set up an icon to run it in Windows 7 without starting Steam, and also run it under Ubuntu without Steam even being installed.  I then requested a download link from Mode7, used it to download the OS X version, and installed that on my MacBook Pro to run without Steam.